# Ionic build ios fails after installing cordova push plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

my ionic build ios fails after i install phonegap plugin :

```
it gives me this error

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/example.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushPlugin.o example/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin/PushPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,example.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,example,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

what does the required environment is missing? I have latest xcode updated and cli versions

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.9.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

Comment: did you trying removing platform/adding platform ? ref: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-plugin-errors-exit-code-65/7274/24

Comment: @pyro yes i tried and it is working

Comment: it is werid the fact that i had to update cordova and ionic and re process everything again to build ios

Comment: I tried but its not working for me..:(

Answer (score 1):

What is your output for cordova platform?

`$ cordova platform
Installed platforms: ios 3.9.2
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, osx, webos`

With ios 4.0.0 I had the same error. 
I changed the platform version and it worked.

`$cordova platform remove ios
$cordova platform add ios@3.9.2`